# Powerpoint inside Excel - linked charts not updating path automatically

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint

I'm updating a tool that enables users to do some basic time series analysis with some data. A series of graphs update automatically when they select different time series from a drop down list. Inserted into the Excel spreadsheet is a PowerPoint presentation that has previously been linked to graphs in the excel spreadsheet so it updates in line with the excel. This is what I'm having difficulty updating.

I'm copying the graph in Excel and then in PowerPoint going Paste Special -> Paste link -> Microsoft Excel Chart Object. This works fine until I try and move the file or change the filename. Rather than link to the file that the PowerPoint file is inserted into, it keeps hold of the full filepath in the linked graphs and continues to point to the original file where the linking took place. All I want it to do is to continue looking in the file that PowerPoint file is inserted into regards of where it is. Embedding isn't an option because there are a lot of graphs and this caused the file to start pushing 200mb I believe (although I'm open to be challenged on this).

They definitely seemed to have got it working last year but they were using Excel 2003. I'm wondering if the Excel 2013 behaviours differently and that this is causing me the issue.

One last requirement on this, due to rules of the organisation I work, VBA is a no-no. I get the feeling that either the solution is really simple or I'm asking for the moon on a stick.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't seem to remember that this kind of links between documents was every able to handle such a change, you could eventually chose the new file to point to, but without VBA you'll be very limited and will have to do this manually for each file!

Comment: Yeah VBA was obvious answer to me. However, I've gone back to the original version and it looks as if the links are somehow shortened to a simple worksheet and cell reference, not the full filepath which is probably why you can move the whole thing around it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I appear to have solved it. Inserting the PowerPoint presentation as 1997-2003 file format means that I can move the excel spreadsheet around and the links continue to reference the file that the PowerPoint file is inserted into. So I've got a 2003 PowerPoint file embedded in a xlsx file.

This suggests to me that the way in which linked charts are handled has changed between the old (2003 and before) and the current versions (2007 and onwards) of PowerPoint.

Comment: To expand on this a little, I found that changing the name of the excel file that the presentation was embedded on resulted in the links being broken. As a result, although I could move the excel file around, the filename of the excel file had to remain the same. Changing the presentation name did not break the links.